# Import unable to locate angular2 in beta.1

Tags: angular, systemjs

The sample code found in [AngularJS 2.0 Getting Started with Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1026938/AngularJS-Getting-Started-with-Visual-Studio) works with alpha.28 version. When I change the scripts from

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.28/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.js"></script>
```

I get an error that says "[local server]/angular2/angular2" is not found.

What has changed since then and how do I configure angular2 to be imported from a CDN?

Comment: Go to [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/), go to *New -> AngularJS -> 2.0.x (TS)* and you'll see the official template. Check the index.html file and you'll see the CDN setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically it is causing error from you app.ts file where you have your component resides.

For importing `Component`, `View` & `bootstrap` old version has `angular2/angular2` path

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
```

Everyone knows day by day angular2 API has changed rapidly.

So as per current version you need to do `angular2/core` for importing `Component, View`

& `bootstrap` should imported from `angular2/platform/browser` js

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common'; //common things are there in common module
```

Other than that `Rx` jx component has been moved out from `angular2.dev.js`, if you have any code related then you need to include `Rx.js` separately in your app.

Also you need to include `angular2-polyfills.js` & `es6-shim.js` js files to enable support for the older application.

[**Angular2 Changelog.md**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)