# Why is visual studio 2015 not recognizing annotations

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular, typescript1.7

Visual Studio is not recognizing the @Componetn or @View Data annotiations?  Does anyone know why this might be occuring.[image]

Update 1

My index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Angular 2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <my-app></my-app>

    <script src="https://github.jspm.io/jmcriffey/bower-traceur-runtime@0.0.87/traceur-runtime.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jspm.io/system@0.16.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.2/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>System.import('app');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

My app.ts file

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {NgFor} from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",

})

@View({
    templateUrl: 'mainForm.html',
    directives: [NgFor]
})

class TodoAppComponent {

    todos: Array<Object>;

    constructor() {
        this.todos = [{ text: "Try Second", done: true }]
    }

    get() {
        return this.todos;
    }

    add($event, newtodo) {

        if ($event.which === 13) {
            this.todos.unshift({ text: newtodo.value, done: false });
            newtodo.value = ''
        }

    }

    markAsDone(todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done;
    }
}

bootstrap(TodoAppComponent);
```

Update 2

Build error in VS2015
[image]

Update 3

This was already in my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "version": "1.7.6",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./app.ts",
        "./typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts",
        "./typings/es6-promise/es6-promise.d.ts",
        "./typings/rx/rx-lite.d.ts",
        "./typings/rx/rx.d.ts",
        "./typings/tsd.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

My Directory Structure, node_nodules to big to expand

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you have trying to import `Component & View` from `angular2/angular2` which has been change in `angular.beta.2.0.0`. So instead you should import  `angular2/core` instead of `angular2/angular2`.

Also make sure all the files are referred on the `index.html`.

Refer this answer for [**more details**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34827468/2435473)

Comment: Basically you need to add setting in tsconfig. Add this to compileOptions ’ "module": "commonjs",
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/app",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true'

Comment: already had that in my tsconfig.json.  boy this is frustrating

Comment: I don't see `outDir` options in your `tsconfig.json`, by having that option, you could transpiled `js` file in other folder like by having `"outDir": "../wwwroot/app",`

Comment: I added outDir... but ti still won't compile/transpile because it still can't find those imports.  It's like it doesn't see angular

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102079/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-droberte).